# Equating Data? Circular Reference? Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of data in Sheet 1, and I use =(VLOOKUP($M$4,'Sheet 1'!$A$3:L1002,6,FALSE)) in Sheet 2 to call a value from Sheet 1. I'm wondering if there is a way so that if I edit the value in sheet 2, it updates the value of the data in Sheet 1? Would I create some kind of a circular reference or use VBA?

Comment: We need details on how sheet2 is structured. If you mean 'I have a formula in column A sheet 2, which references column A sheet 1', and you want column A sheet 1 to update when you update column A sheet 2, then yes, that is a circular reference.

Comment: Thanks that is what i mean! How would I code that circular reference? I haven't used that before @Grade'Eh'Bacon

Comment: A circular reference is something to avoid, not attempt to reach. Please edit your question to include in detail what your actual *problem* is. For exampe - do you have an original data list, but you want to edit your data list on sheet2 after it has been sorted? Give more concrete information about how your data table is laid out, etc.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, updating the value in Sheet2 will destroy your Vlookup formula. Not what I think you want. Now if you use the cell next to the VLookup formula for the update then you could use the WorkSheet_Change event to trigger code to update your data in Sheet1. However, this would be tricky since your code would have to determine which row VLookup pulled the data from, but this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if, for example, you want the contents of column A in sheet1 to reflect changes in column A in sheet2 and vise versa then it cannot be done with formulas as, as you suggest, it will create a circular reference.

So I believe the best way to tackle it is to program some VBA to do it. But be careful not to create an infinite loop! (eg changing sheet1 changes sheet2 and changing sheet2 changes sheet1 ....)